# React native add new items in state array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have below code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation'
import {Keyboard, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import EditableTable from 'react-native-editable-table';

export default class CreateNoteScreen extends Component {


constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        NotesHeader : [
          {value: 'Expend', input: 'c1', width: 30, sortable: false, defaultSort: 'ASC',editable: true},
          {value: 'Value', input: 'c2', width: 20, sortable: false, editable: true}
        ],
        NotesValue: [
          [10, 'test'],
          [20, {value: 'Edit Me', editable: true}],
          [30, {value: 'Extra Editable Rows',editable:true}],
          [20, {value: 'Edit Me', editable: true}],
          [20, {value: 'Edit Me', editable: true}],
          [20, {value: 'Edit Me', editable: true}],
          [20, {value: 'Edit Me', editable: true}],
          [20, {value: 'Edit Me', editable: true}],
          [10, 'test'],
          ['', ''],
          ['', '']
        ]
    }
}
_addNewColumn = () =>{

  let newNotesvalues = this.state.NotesValue.map(function(item) {
    item = [...item,[ 
      '',
      {
      value: ' ',
      editable: true
    }]]
    return item;
  });

this.setState(prevState => ({
  NotesHeader: [...prevState.NotesHeader, {
    value: 'Value',
    input: 'c3',
    width: 20,
    sortable: false,
    editable: true
  }],
  NotesValue: newNotesvalues
}))


//   let newNotesvalues = this.state.NotesValue.map(function(item) {
//     item.push({value: ' ', editable: true})
//     return item;
// });
//  let newHeadervalues = this.state.NotesHeader.concat({value: 'Value', input: 'c3', width: 20, sortable: false, editable: true});
//  console.warn(newHeadervalues)
//  console.warn(newNotesvalues)
// this.setState(prevState => ({
//   NotesHeader: newHeadervalues,
//   NotesValue: newNotesvalues
// }))
  // this.setState(prevState => ({
  //   NotesHeader: newHeadervalues, //[...prevState.NotesHeader,this.state.NotesHeader.push({value: 'Value', input: 'c3', width: 20, sortable: false, editable: true})],
  //   NotesValue: newNotesvalues
  // }))

 // console.warn(this.state)
}
render(){
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Add column" onPress={() => this._addNewColumn()} />
        <EditableTable
          columns ={ this.state.NotesHeader }
          values= {this.state.NotesValue}
          emptyRows={2}
          onCellChange={(value, column, row, unique_id) => {
            console.log(`Cell Change on Column: ${column} Row: ${row}
                        and unique_id: ${unique_id}`);
          }}
          onColumnChange={(value, oldVal, newVal) => {
            console.log(`Column Change. Old Value: ${oldVal} New Value: ${newVal}`)
          }}
          customStyles={{

          }}
          style={styles.table}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  table: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 30
  }
});
```

NoteHeader is table header and NoteValue is table rows

*_addNewColumn* I want to add new column and blank values in rows.

https://snack.expo.io/HkZmuoVLS

Its throwing error, I tried with few variations but could not a success.

> Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
>       at eval (module://react-native-editable-table.js:3:4930)

Please help also will be helpful if guid through best way

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting as well?

Comment: This is plugin error undefined not an object

Answer (score 0):

`Array#push` returns a new length of an array, and then you try to add that to `NotesHeader` via spreading. Change it to this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  NotesHeader: [...prevState.NotesHeader, {
    value: 'Value',
    input: 'c3',
    width: 20,
    sortable: false,
    editable: true
  }],
  NotesValue: newNotesvalues
}))
```

Also use array spreading in `_addNewColumn`

```
_addNewColumn = () => {

  let newNotesvalues = this.state.NotesValue.map(function(item) {
    item = [...item, {
      value: ' ',
      editable: true
    }]
    return item;
  });
}
```

Comment: let newNotesvalues = this.state.NotesValue.map(function(item) {
        return [...item, ' ' ]
      });

Comment: It should be above I have checked in jsfiddle its giving correct output in console but in react native its adding alot extra